# How to switch to "ひらがな"　mode　from　”直接入力”　mode by pressing a key stock (or key stocks) on keyboard?

Tags: shortcut-keys

Take a look at the screenshot :
[image: Screenshot]

For example, in Windows, MS Pinyin input method, you can switch between "English" and "Chinese" mode by pressing the <kbd>Shift</kbd>  key.

Or, even able to set "ひらがな" mode as the default mode is better than now.

Comment: English version of the same screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TYvqE.png

Comment: I haven't tried it myself, but does this answer your question https://askubuntu.com/questions/561486/how-do-i-switch-input-modes-in-mozc-without-going-to-the-ibus-menu

Comment: What program is the menu part of? If it is Ibus-mozc, either the above comment or this [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/717098/make-ibus-mozc-start-in-hiragana-rather-than-direct-input-mode) might have an answer you can use.

Comment: Must be Ibus-mozc. this is the source repository: https://github.com/google/mozc

Comment: Thanks to @Frankie0p . In the thread, I found this answer works: https://askubuntu.com/a/886698/751297 . Now I'm using Ctrl+Space to switch between 直接入力 and ひらがな。